# Copying polymorphic objects

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I have a question regarding copying polymorphic objects. My starting point is the usual example of how to implement a clone-function:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
  protected:
    int a;

  public:
    void set_a(int x) { a = x; }
    void get_a() { std::cout << a << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Base() {}

    virtual Base *clone() const = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    virtual Derived *clone() const
    {
        return new Derived(*this);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Base *ptr = new Derived;
    ptr->set_a(20);
    ptr->get_a();

    Base *cpy = ptr->clone();
    cpy->get_a();
}
```

Why does the line `new Derived(*this)` result in a copying of `this`? Is it because we call the copy constructor of `Derived` with `this` as argument?

If we are indeed calling the copy constructor of `Derived`, then why doesn't the following compile:

```
Base *b = new Derived(ptr); //does not compile
```

Comment: `ptr` is of type `Base*`, why `new Derived(ptr);` should compile?

Comment: A copy constructor, by definition, copies an instance of the same class. `ptr` is not an instance of the same class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it because we call the copy constructor of `Derived`?

Absolutely. `*this` expression inside `Derived::clone` is of type `Derived&`, so `Derived::Derived(const Derived& original)` copy constructor is called.

> Why doesn't the following compile:
>
> ```
> Base *b = new Derived(ptr);
> ```

This call does not compile because `ptr` is a pointer, not a reference. This would compile, but it would be pointless in the context of cloning:

```
Base *b = new Derived(*ptr);
```

The point of cloning is that you don't know what type you get as the result; when you do `new Derived(*ptr)` you specify the type explicitly.